# SQL Server - Como criar uma nova tabela usando um select de outra tabela (Ambas no mesmo Banco de dados)

Tags: sql-server

Eu fiz um script sql juntando algumas tabelas no SQL Server e terei o resultado em alguns campos, mas gostaria criar uma nova tabela e copiar tudo o que filtrei com select para dentro dela... Algo como: create table Enderecos_new as (meu script sql....).

Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Obrigado :)

```js
Select 
loc.loc_nu_sequencial, 

CASE
 WHEN
  loc.cep IS NULL
 THEN logr.cep 
 WHEN
  logr.cep IS NULL
 THEN loc.cep 
 ELSE loc.cep
END AS cep,

 logr.log_nome,
 logr.log_complemento,
 log_bairro.bai_no,
 loc.loc_no,
 loc.ufe_sg 
  
  from log_localidade as loc

  left join log_logradouro as logr on loc.loc_nu_sequencial = logr.loc_nu_sequencial
  left join log_bairro on logr.bai_nu_sequencial_ini = log_bairro.bai_nu_sequencial

  order by loc_nu_sequencial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `INTO` no seu código. O nome informado nele será utilizado na criação da nova tabela.

```
SELECT 
    loc.loc_nu_sequencial, 
    CASE
        WHEN loc.cep IS NULL THEN logr.cep 
        WHEN logr.cep IS NULL THEN loc.cep 
        ELSE loc.cep
    END AS cep,
    logr.log_nome,
    logr.log_complemento,
    log_bairro.bai_no,
    loc.loc_no,
    loc.ufe_sg 
INTO nova_tabela
FROM log_localidade AS loc
    LEFT JOIN log_logradouro as logr 
        ON loc.loc_nu_sequencial = logr.loc_nu_sequencial
    LEFT JOIN log_bairro 
        ON logr.bai_nu_sequencial_ini = log_bairro.bai_nu_sequencial
ORDER BY loc_nu_sequencial
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql

Comment: Valeu Camilo!!!